# Manipulating data after retrieved it from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here's my code:

//Get data from Firebase

```
    func getData(withBlock completion:@escaping() ->Void){
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("hobbies")
    let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "cost").queryEqual(toValue: "low")
    query.observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
        self.user_choice_Cost.append((snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "hobbyName").value as? String)!)
        completion()
        //print(self.user_choice_Cost)
    })
    { (error) in
    print(error)
    }
```

//Manipulating data

```
    getData{
    let set2:Set<String> = ["a"]
    let set1:Set<String> = Set(self.user_choice_Cost)
    print(set1.union(set2))}
```

This works correctly! But is there any way I can get the user_choice_Cost with all value(["a","b"]) instead of one by one(["a"],["a","b")] and manipulate user_choice_Cost array without putting it inside inside getData{}. Because if I put that outside it will return only "a"

Comment: Why don't you create model classes for your data ?

Comment: this is just a quick draft. Is it better if I create model classes ? Will it solve the one by one value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you observe `.childAdded`, your completion handler gets called for each individual child that matches your query. If you want to get called only once for all matching children, you should observe `.value`:

```
    query.observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
```

Since your completion handler gets called only once, the snapshot in this case contains all matching nodes. So you need to loop over `snapshot.children`:

```
    query.observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let value: String = (child.childSnapshot(forPath: "hobbyName").value as? String)!;
            user_choice_Cost.append(value)
        }
        print("value \(user_choice_Cost)")
    })
```

With this code you'll only see one logging output, with all matching hobby names.